# Is it possible to pass more than one complex type parameter separately in the web API 2 Controller post method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, webapi2

I know [FromBody] allows only one complex type as a parameter. I just wanted to know, is there any other way to do so?  Any help or knowledge would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

1. This is my controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]  List<TranInOutDtl> tranInOutDtl, List<TranInOutDtlsub> tranDtlSub, List<TranInOutDtlsub> tranDtlSub)
```

2. This is my complex object below

```
        public partial class TranInOutDtl
        {
        public int Tranno { get; set; }
        public int Trannosub { get; set; }
        public string ProdTypeDesc { get; set; }
        public string BatchNo { get; set; }
        public string Itemno { get; set; }
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
        public decimal ScanPendQty { get; set; }
        public int TotalBoxqty { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public int BoxQty { get; set; }
        public bool Isdone { get; set; }
        public int PKId { get; set; }
        public int PKSubId { get; set; }
        public string PkBxDesc { get; set; }
        public int BoxSz { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class TranInOutDtlsub
        {
        public int Tranno { get; set; }
        public int Trannosub { get; set; }
        public int Trannosub1 { get; set; }
        public string RackShlvNo { get; set; }
        public string ShlvNo { get; set; }
        public int ShlvBoxQty { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public int BoxQty { get; set; }
        public bool Isdonesub { get; set; }
        public string RkShlvSelType { get; set; }
        public string RkShCatUId { get; set; }
        public string RackCatDesc { get; set; }
        public string RkShCatColorCode { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class TranInOutRackScan
        {
        public int Tranno { get; set; }
        public int Trannosub { get; set; }
        public int Trannosub1 { get; set; }
        public int Srno { get; set; }
        public string BarcodeNo { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public int BoxQty { get; set; }
        public string InOut { get; set; }
        public int PackMaster_ID { get; set; }
        public int Pack_type_ID { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Just make a class that has one of each of these as a property and use that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was mentioned by DavidG you could create any complex types that will suit your specific needs so for example

```
public class TranInOutContainer 
{
    public List<TranInOutDtl> TranInOutDtl Dtl {get; set;}
    public List<TranInOutDtlsub> TranDtlSub DtlSub {get; set;} 
    ....
}
```

will be valid solution for your problem

You could also use `dynamic` type ofc but it should be used only if no other solution exists